# Tabletop miniature gaming modeling and painting questions?

Tags: discussion

Since BCG allows questions on tabletop miniature games (e.g., Warhammer 40K and Flames of War), does it also include questions on activities integral to (some) tabletop miniature games? Specifically, modeling and painting questions?

Revised: added example painting/modeling questions.

Example painting question: How to speed-paint a mob of Ork Boyz?

Example modeling question: How to indicate a mob of Ork Boyz all belong to the same unit?

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/311/50.

Comment: Thank you. I am embarrassed I did not perform a better search before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing the games (only saw them and know the general flow of gaming) I think if you are asking a particular question (one that doesn't sound like, should I paint this red or blue?) would be ok. At least I don't see anything that will break the faq. Particular questions are ok, but don't ask for opinions, that are better on a poll. But this type of question, besides all I said, should be validated,because are not gaming per se questions...

edit:

I just open the [faq](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq) and it said that among the question that you can ask are

> Minature wargames (including the preparation of
>   miniatures/terrain/etc)

Comment: Thanks! I realized from your rseponse I should include example questions and will revise my question.

Comment: My apologies. I should have re-checked the FAQ.